# Popup displays outside of the map using Mapbox API in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox

I am trying to display a popup on click referring to this code: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/popup-on-click/

My problem is the popup displays outside of the container. I am not getting why is it behaving that way.

My main component:

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN;

const MapDiv = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  .map-container {
    height: 70vh;
    width: 60vw;
  }
`;

export default function PoolsRelay() {
  const mapContainer = useRef(null);
  const map = useRef(null);
  let test;
  const [lng, setLng] = useState(-70.9);
  const [lat, setLat] = useState(42.35);
  const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (map.current) return; //initialize map only once
    test = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: mapContainer.current,
      ref: map.current,
      style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v10",
      center: [lng, lat],
      zoom: 0,
      scrollZoom: true,
      boxZoom: true,
      doubleClickZoom: true,
      dragPan: true,
    });

    const popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({
      closeButton: true,
      closeOnClick: false,
    });
    // create default markers
    CreateMarkers(test, popup);
  });

  return (
    <div className={"default-margin"}>
      <h1 className={"text-black h1"}>Map</h1>
      <MapDiv>
        <RelaysList />
        <div ref={mapContainer} className={"map-container"} />
      </MapDiv>
    </div>
  );
}
```

CreateMarkers component to plot the markers from Geojson data and handle popup. Link: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/data/stations.geojson

```
export default function createMarkers(test, popup) {
  // handles popup
  const PopupHandler = () => {
    test.on("click", "points", function (e) {
      const coordinates = e.features[0].geometry.coordinates.slice();
      const description = e.features[0].properties.description;
      //Ensure that if the map is zoomed out such that multiple
      // copies of the feature are visible, the popup appears
      // over the copy being pointed to
      while (Math.abs(e.lngLat.lng - coordinates[0]) > 180) {
        coordinates[0] += e.lngLat.lng > coordinates[0] ? 360 : -360;
      }
      popup.setLngLat(coordinates).setHTML(description).addTo(test);
    });
  };

  test.on("load", function () {
    test.loadImage(MarkerImg, function (error, image) {
      if (error) throw error;
      test.addImage("custom-marker", image);
      // Add a GeoJSON source with 2 points
      test.addSource("points", {
        type: "geojson",
        data: GeoJson,
      });

      // Add a symbol layer
      test.addLayer({
        id: "points",
        type: "symbol",
        source: "points",
        layout: {
          "icon-image": "custom-marker",
        },
      });
      test.on("mouseenter", "points", function () {
        // change the cursor style as a UI indicator
        test.getCanvas().style.cursor = "pointer";
      });
      test.on("mouseleave", "points", function () {
        test.getCanvas().style.cursor = "";
      });
      {
        PopupHandler();
      }
    });
  });
}
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: Have you added mapbox css ? 

<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.2.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: yes, i had but i did not replace the version number. i feel stupid now lol. Thank you very much. It works fine now.

Comment: Thanks, it was due to css misposition